# Calculate the sum of interior angles of a polygon - follow-up

Tags: c

This is a follow-up review of [Calculate the sum of interior angles of a polygon](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/231898/calculate-the-sum-of-interior-angles-of-a-polygon).

Using the helpful answers from the original post, I have integrated the suggestions which are in order from first to last:

- Adding checks to `scanf()`.
- Using `main(void)` in place of `main(...)`.
- Passing `char *` directly to `printf()`.
- Made conditionals simpler.
- `main()` is broken up into several functions and subroutines.

I am seeking a second peer review because I have also added changes not suggested in the original post which are:

- Using enumerations to convey error information.
- Heavier error-checking in function `askAgain()`.

````c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


/* Keep string constants of the questions. */

const char* howManySides =
"How many sides does the shape have? ";

const char* askAnotherShape =
"Would you like to find interior angles for another polygon? (0 or 1) ";

/* Table of polygon names from 3 to 12 sides */
const char* names[] = {
    "a triangle",
    "a quadrilateral",
    "a pentagon",
    "a hexagon",
    "a heptagon",
    "an octagon",
    "a nonagon",
    "a decagon",
    "a hendecagon",
    "a dodecagon"
};

enum errorType {noError, errNegSides, errZeroSides, errInsufSides};



static int getSumInteriorAngles(const unsigned int numSides)
{
    return 180 * (numSides - 2);
}



/* Print a specific type of error based on its enumeration.
   */
static void printError(const enum errorType eType)
{
    switch(eType) {
        case errNegSides:
        printf("The number of sides cannot be negative...\n");
        break;

        case errZeroSides:
        printf("The number of sides cannot be zero...\n");
        break;

        case errInsufSides:
        printf("The shape must have at least 3 sides...\n");
        break;
    }
}



/* Takes a number of polygon sides and returns a type of error if the number
   of sides invalid or no error type if the number of sides is valid.
   */
static enum errorType isSidesValid(const int numSides)
{
    if(numSides < 0) return errNegSides;
    else if(numSides == 0) return errZeroSides;
    else if(numSides < 3) return errInsufSides;
    else return noError;
}



static int getUserInput(void)
{
    int userInput;
    bool isValidResponse = false;

    while(!isValidResponse) {
        /* Ask for the number of sides. */
        printf(howManySides);

        /* We're looking for exactly 1 argument, so if there's
           less than that, then something went wrong with the conversion. */
        if(scanf("%i", &userInput) < 1) {
            printf("Not a number...\n");
            fflush(stdin);

            /* This check failed, so repeat the question. */
            continue;
        }
        isValidResponse = true;
    }
    return userInput;
}



static int getNumSides(void)
{
    int numSides;

    /* Initialize the checks flag to false and make it true only when
       all checks pass. */
    bool passedAllChecks = false;


    while(!passedAllChecks) {
        numSides = getUserInput();

        /* If the input was a valid number, then we have to check if the
           number of sides makes sense. */
        enum errorType returnError = isSidesValid(numSides);

        if(returnError != noError) {
            /* If the number doesn't make sense for a number of sides,
               then print the specific error and repeat the question. */
            printError(returnError);
            continue;
        }

        /* All checks passed. Exit the loop and return the number of sides. */
        passedAllChecks = true;
    }
    return numSides;
}



static int askAgain(void)
{
    int userResponse = 0;
    bool isValidResponse = false;

    while(!isValidResponse) {
        printf(askAnotherShape);

        /* Weed out non-integers and other weirdness. */
        if(scanf("%i", &userResponse) < 1) {
            printf("Not a valid response...\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            continue;
        }

        /* Restrict valid input to 0 or 1. */
        if((userResponse != 0) && (userResponse != 1)) {
            printf("Please choose 0 or 1...\n");
            continue;
        }
        isValidResponse = true;
    }
    return userResponse;
}



static void printResult(int numSides)
{
    /* Assume we're dealing with a polygon without a special name,
       in which case, we'll refer to it non-specifically. */
    const char *name = "this polygon";

    /* If we have a name for this polygon, then get it from the table. */
    if(numSides <= 12) {
        name = names[numSides - 3];
    }

    printf("The sum of the interior angles of %s is %i\n",
            name, getSumInteriorAngles(numSides));
}



int main(void)
{
    do {
        printResult(getNumSides());
    } while(askAgain());

    return 0;
}

```
````

Comment: @Jamal Thank you for the edit. Can you explain why some of the function references have a ```)``` missing while others have matching parentheses? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### String as formats

Code uses `printf(howManySides);` yet `howManySides` is not described as a *format*.  Such practice can lead to trouble when the string contains a `%`.  Do not use a string as a *format* unless it is clearly stated in its definition that it is a *format*.

```
// printf(howManySides);
fputs(howManySides, stdout);
```

### Ensure output before input

`stdout` may be byte, line, or fully buffered.   Insure output is seen before requesting user input.  Often printing a `'\n'` is sufficient - except that the code here does not have that in the prompts.  `fflush(stdout)` always works.

```
printf(howManySides);
fflush(stdout); // add
if(scanf("%i", &userInput) < 1) {
```

### Avoid undefined behavior

See why not to use [`fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin).

Tip: ditch `scanf()`; use `fgets()` for robust error handing.

### Infinite loop

Should `scanf("%i", &userInput) < 1)` return `EOF` due to end-of-file, code loops infinitely.  Instead, when the return is `EOF`, consider ending the program or at least get out of the loop.

### Avoid magic numbers

Rather than hard code `3, 12` and their effects in various places in code, create constants.

```
#define POLY_MIN 3
#define POLY_N   (sizeof names/sizeof names[0])
#define POLY_MAX (POLY_N + POLY_MIN - 1)

// if(numSides <= 12) {
//  name = names[numSides - 3];
if(numSides <= POLY_MAX) {
  name = names[numSides - POLY_MIN];
```

### Avoid naked equations

Sure `180 * (numSides - 2)` is grade school math, yet often a reference is useful.

```
// en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_and_external_angles#Properties
return 180 * (numSides - 2);
```

---

## Minor stuff

### Curious type selection

Unclear why `getSumInteriorAngles()` uses `unsigned`.  Function is only used once and it is called with `int`

```
// static int getSumInteriorAngles(const unsigned int numSides)
static int getSumInteriorAngles(const int numSides)
```

### Sometimes `const`, sometimes not

Some functions declare parameters as `const` and others do not, even though the parameter is not modified in both.  Hmmm.  IAC, I see it more as clutter than useful.  As with such style issues, code to your group's coding standard.

### `do` loop candidate

```
bool isValidResponse = false;
while(!isValidResponse) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your review. In ```getUserInput()```, how can I use ```fgets()``` to check if the input is strictly an integer?

Comment: I would use `strtol` (`stdlib.h`) and check the result carefully, then cast to `int` when you are sure it's between `[INT_MIN, INT_MAX]` (`limits.h`.) https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html

Comment: @Neil Also when the result is outside the `int` range, it should be set to `INT_MAX/INT_MIN` and set `errno`.

Comment: As seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29378380/2472827 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/57860925/2472827.

Answer (score 3):

We can eliminate the magic number `12` here:

> ```
> /* If we have a name for this polygon, then get it from the table. */
> if(numSides <= 12) {
>     name = names[numSides - 3];
> }
> ```

The common idiom for determining the number of elements in an array works by using the size of the array and the size of each element:

```
static const int max_sides = sizeof names / sizeof *names;
```

We can eliminate the constant `3` even more easily, by including dummy (unused) elements at the beginning of the array:

```
/* polygon names up to 12 sides */
const char* names[] = {
    "(point)",
    "(line)",
    "(line)",
    "a triangle",
    "a quadrilateral",
    "a pentagon",
    "a hexagon",
```

Here, I've included some descriptive strings for the invalid cases, which makes debugging easier should we accidentally use one of them.  We could save a tiny bit of program size by making them null pointers instead.

With those changes, the code I quoted becomes this:

```
/* If we have a name for this polygon, then get it from the table. */

static const int max_sides = sizeof names / sizeof *names;

if (numSides < max_sides) {
    name = names[numSides];
}
```

Or, making it constant:

```
const char *const name = numSides < max_sides
                         ? names[numSides]
                         : "this polygon";
```